# Mapping property from nested model into extjs form view

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

I have a `JSON` like:

```
{
 "id": "d258832c-c454-4961-9013-40ab222930d9",
 "name": "CDS_BU",
 "description": null,
 "parentId": null,
 "group": {
   "id": "ef01eb78-2ae0-43ed-844e-57a825b046eb",
   "name": "GroupForCDSBU2"
 }
}
```

And I have a `form` and view for this object, but I am unable to show the current value for `group.name` in the form when loading.

The current form extends from `Ext.form.Panel` and I am using `initComponent` to assign the values to the form. I.E.

```
    me.items = [{
        name:       'name',
        xtype:      'textfield',
        fieldLabel: "Name"
    }, {
        name:       'description',
        xtype:      'textareafield',
        fieldLabel: "Comments"
    }]
```

This currently work and shows the values from `description` and `name`.

I have created a model for the group like:

```
Ext.define('GroupModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'string',
    useNull: true
  }, {
    name: 'name',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'string',
    useNull: true
  }]
});
```

And another model for the Parent Object which we will name `Parent`, like:

```
 Ext.define('ParentEditModel', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
   {
     name: 'name',
     defaultValue: ''
   }, {
    name: 'description',
    defaultValue: ''
   }
   ...
   ]
```

To this last model I tried a `hasOne` association

like:

```
   hasOne: {model: 'GroupModel', name: 'group' }
```

and added a new field to it with the following signature:

```
   {name: 'groupName', mapping: 'group.name'}
```

Obviously this does not work, because as far as I understand this needs an `associationKey` which I don't have in my current `model`.

**In a nutshell, how can I map these two parameters (group: id, name) to inputs in the form view.**

Comment: I had a similar issues with nested JSON, I tried using associations, the association itself worked BUT I was unable to get the association data into my grid panel, at least for the gridpanel it was not possible to create such a mapping.

I realize you are not trying to use grid panels but my workaround solution might help you.

In my situation, I wrote a function to flatten the nested JSON data BEFORE loading it into the store, this was the quickest and most pain free solution to my issue, that avoided having to use associations.

Comment: thanks @user2574678, that's exactly what I was doing, I added a property called `groupName` and another `groupExternalId`, and was setting it on intializing and didn't work for me, but that's a different question.

Comment: If you want to set up a fiddle example, I can take a look this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario you don't need an associated model, you can use the mapping in your parent model and no association key or anything else is required.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncLvaupn/

```
 Ext.define('ParentEditModel', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
   {
     name: 'name',
     defaultValue: ''
   }, {
    name: 'description',
    defaultValue: ''
   }, {
    name: 'groupName',
    mapping: 'group.name'
   }
   ...
   ]
```